# Closed form for $\int z^n\ln{(z)}\ln{(1-z)}\,\mathrm{d}z$?

Tags: integration, logarithms, special-functions, indefinite-integrals, polylogarithm

> **Problem.** Find an anti-derivative for the following indefinite integral, where $n$ is a non-negative integer:
>   $$\int z^n\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z=~???$$

---

**My attempt:**

Euler's reflection identity for dilogarithms states,

$$\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}=\zeta{(2)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}.\tag{1}$$

Using identity $(1)$, our integral may be split up into three integrals, the first of which is elementary:

$$\begin{align}
\int z^n\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int z^n\left[\zeta{(2)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\zeta{(2)}\int z^n\,\mathrm{d}z-\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z-\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\zeta{(2)}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}-\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z-\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

Wolfram Alpha gives anti-derivatives for the two dilogarithmic integrals in terms of hypergeometric functions:

$$\small{\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\ln{(1-z)}+\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}+\frac{z^{n+2}}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}{_2F_1}{\left(1,n+2;n+3;z\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}};$$

$$\small{\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z=-\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}+\frac{z^{n+1}\ln{(z)}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{z^{n+1}\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(1-z\right)}}{n+1}-\frac{z^{n+1}\ln{(z)}}{(n+1)^2}{_2F_1}{\left(1,n+2;n+3;z\right)}+\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}{_3F_2}{\left(1,n+1,n+1;n+2,n+2;z\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}}.$$

Now, if we permit closed forms in terms of hypergeometric functions, then we might consider the problem solved. However, in my experience hypergeometric functions of integer parameters often have representations in terms of simpler functions, and I wonder if that might not be the case here. Does the anti-derivative sought have a more mundane representation that avoids hypergeometric functions?

Comment: Welcome to $10\,\mathbb{K}$ club David. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you Tunk. Were you by chance the person who bumped me over 10k?

Comment: Yup! I just upvote 15 rep. Anyway, call me Ari. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Integration by parts seems enough.
$$\int z^n\ln z\ln(1-z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln z\ln(1-z)-\frac{1}{n+1}\int z^{n+1}\left(\frac{\ln(1-z)}{z}-\frac{\ln z}{1-z}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z$$

Now
\begin{align}
\int z^n\ln(1-z)\,\mathrm{d}z&=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(1-z)-\int \frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)(z-1)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(1-z)-\frac{\ln(1-z)}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\int\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(1-z)-\frac{\ln(1-z)}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{z^k}{k}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int \frac{z^{n+1}}{1-z}\ln z\,\mathrm{d}z &= \int\frac{\ln z}{1-z}-\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}\ln z\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{z^k}{k}\ln z-\frac{z^k}{k^2}\right)
\end{align}

Putting these together, we get
$$\int z^n\ln z\ln(1-z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln z\ln(1-z)-\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(1-z)+\frac{\ln(1-z)}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{z^k}{k}\ln z-\frac{k+n+1}{k^2(n+1)}z^k\right)$$

I hope there aren't any typos. :)

Comment: Very nice answer ! This is what I was trying to do (but no success). Thanks for that.

Comment: +1) This seems to be just what I was looking for. I'm going to take a few minutes to work through the calculations for myself, but then I plan on accepting this response.

Answer (score 2):

For the second antiderivative, it can be simplified to $$\int z^n\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac{z^{n+1} ((n+1) \text{Li}_2(z)+\log (1-z))+B_z(n+2,0)}{(n+1)^2}$$ However, for the third one, I did not arrive to anything significantly different from your own result.

I am pretty sure that there is a way to make all of that simpler since, defining $$I_n=\int z^n\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z$$ for any positive integer value of $n$, a "quite simple" expression is obtained (in which $\zeta(2)$ never appears).

So, basically, I wonder if the use Euler's reflection identity for dilogarithms states does not make the problem more complex in terms of resulting functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My gut agrees with you that starting out by using Euler's identity may complicate matters more than it simplifies them.

Comment: Karvens's answer seems to be **the** answer ! Cheers !